# Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element

Tags: xml

I am facing "Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element" error when I am trying to validate xml against xsd.
I am pasting below first few lines of xml and xsd.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VMxRqDef targetNamespace="http://firstdatacorp.com/framework/core/vmx/MsgIn" 
xmlns="http://firstdatacorp.com/framework/core/vmx/MsgIn" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<VMX_ROOT>
```

XSD:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
 <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://firstdatacorp.com/framework/core/vmx/MsgIn"            xmlns="http://firstdatacorp.com/framework/core/vmx/MsgIn"    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:complexType name="VMxRqDef">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="VMX_ROOT">
```

Request you to help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined a root *element* in your Xml Schema, just a *type*. Probably, you want your schema to define an *element* with the name that you are currently assigning to the complex type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://firstdatacorp.com/framework/core/vmx/MsgIn" xmlns="http://firstdatacorp.com/framework/core/vmx/MsgIn" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="VMxRqDef">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="VMX_ROOT">
```

... and then complete the hierarchy by adding closing tags as required.

If you actually want to give the complex type a name (so it can be used in other elements, as well), you can also do so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://firstdatacorp.com/framework/core/vmx/MsgIn" xmlns="http://firstdatacorp.com/framework/core/vmx/MsgIn" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="VMxRqDef" type="VMxRqDefType"/>

<xs:complexType name="VMxRqDefType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="VMX_ROOT">
```